# How to use gradle run with Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have the following `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = "MyMain"

allprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
}
```

So when I do `gradle run` it works perfectly, it uses jsoup and so.

Now, I've imported this project at my Intellij Idea IDE, I created a gradle build run/debug configuration, so when I press the green arrow 'run', it's building the application, but not running it, so I guess it's executing `gradle build`.

I've searched for an way to run the application, and the Intellij Idea says that I must create a new Application run/debug configuration. I did it, told where my main class was, but when I click run, it tries to make the source code, and claims that it can't find Jsoup for compiling.

How can I mimic `gradle run` in intellij idea's IDE?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry, it was automatically suggested and I clicked

Comment: Gotcha. Okay, now, then what do you mean by "mimic"?

Comment: I think you are missing `apply plugin: 'java'`...

Comment: @cricket_007 I've read that i don't need this when I apply application

Comment: @cricket_007 The `application` plugin applies the `java` plugin automatically, no need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 17):

You need to delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle

[image: Idea preferences (screenshot)]

Answer (score 13):

Open the gradle window in Intellij. View->Tool Windows->Gradle.

On the right hand side you will see a list of all your gradle tasks. Double click to run or right click and assign a shortcut to any of them.

Answer (score 4):

Look for the [Gradle Tool Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/gradle-tool-window.html). The rest is self-explanatory :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to click "Refresh all Gradle projects" in that tool window each time you change the build script.